# Does anyone have working example connecting to Jira Cloud and searching for issues?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

Looking for Plain REST or Java code.
Jira "official" java client doesn't work with cloud version. REST guide is way too generic and I failed to understand how to pass auth. 
Thank you.

Comment: How about using postman tool as a rest client, if success than try to use a spring rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work

1. login and create token https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens
2. read about using api tokens https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-basic-authentication/
3. try `curl -v https://YOUR_DOMAIN.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/BACK-555 --user your_login@your.company:api-key`

Should work.

now I'm looking for java DTO/Beans for Jira cloud responses :) They are huuge.

Comment: Hi! Did you found a java example doing this? (jira cloud authentication using api key) Thank you for a hint!

Comment: Example above worked for me.  I gave up on bean mapping. We decided to go with Monday.